# Possible logical meanings of mathematical operations

Tags: logic

I'm wondering if there are logical meanings for the mathematical operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division) , from the perspective of each operand?

Comment: In $\mathbb{F}_2 = ℤ/2ℤ$, if you interpret zero as *false* and one as *true*, “$+$” (and “$-$”) corresponds to *exclusive or* and “$·$” corresponds to *and*.

Comment: See [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Comment: I will propose some ideas:

Comment: if we have two persons, the first's length = 8, and the second 's length = 2, now if the first looked to the second , then the perception of the first to the second should be that the second is more little than he's really is , and the other way, if the second looked to the first , then the first will be percepted as taller than he's really is.

Comment: now if any one looks to him self then the perception is going to be normal, not taller not smaller

Comment: that was the logic part, now for the mathematical part,

Comment: 8 / 2 = 4, 2 / 8 = 1 / 4, 2 / 2 = 1 or 8 / 8 =  1

Comment: the logical interpretation:     8 to 2 is more than normal  i.e: 4 > 1, 2 to 8 is less than normal i.e: 1/4  <  1, and the 2 to 2 is normal i.e: 1

Comment: now for how to use it :  if we have a problem which include as given ... something is w.r.t something else = some quantity, then that should be modeled as  second something / first something = quantity

Comment: now, i need some mathematician to tell me if all of this feasible or not, and if so , how to develop it to ease the understanding of mathematics, because I'm too too too weak in mathematics

Comment: But we already have the "less than" and "greater than" relations between *magnitudes*; we define e.g. "greater or equal" as "not-less than" (i.e.$a \ge b$ iff $\lnot a < b$) and we may use those "basic" relations to build up logical complex statement with "and", "or", "not" ...